# Auto Submit form just once

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, form-submit

I have configured the javascript code to do auto submit but what I want is that if the authentication fails, I do not do the autosubmit again.
My code is the following:

Form:

```
<?php echo form_open($this->uri->uri_string(), array('class' => 'login-form')); ?>
    <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="email"><?php echo _l('clients_login_email'); ?></label>

                    <input type="text" autofocus="true" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">

                    <?php echo form_error('email'); ?>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="password"><?php echo _l('clients_login_password'); ?></label>

                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password">

                    <?php echo form_error('password'); ?>

                </div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
        var auto = setTimeout(function(){ autoRefresh(); }, 100);

        function submitform(){
            document.forms["login-form"].submit();
        }

        function autoRefresh(){
            clearTimeout(auto);
            auto = setTimeout(function(){ submitform(); autoRefresh(); }, 10000);
        }
    }
</script>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Where is the authentication code?

Comment: Sorry, I just added it

Comment: Are you using code-igniter?

Comment: Yes, i'm using codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem lies in `array('class' => 'login-form')`.

Looking at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms#Getting_form_information) for `document.forms`, you access the forms with ID.

I am not familiar with code-igniter; however, your code tells me that you are probably setting the class for a form. You would need to set the id for a form.

---

For preventing the auto-submit from running twice. From what I see, I suspect that you are getting a normal HTML form at the end. When you submit a HTML form it would make a trip to the server and when it comes back it should reload the page (unless you make it an asynchronous form).

Since the page is reloading, the window.onload would be run every time. To prevent this you would have to use a true-false flag some wheres.

Here are some potential solutions:

- You could try looking into accessing url parameters from JavaScript. Some quick searching shows that this is a lot more complex than I'd expect though...
- Alternatively, you could move the JavaScript code into a `<script>` block and echo out a script block from PHP. If you are going with this option you should look into using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method instead of accessing `onload` directly. PHP would make it much easier to accessing URL parameters by using `$_GET` or `$_POST`.
- A second alternative would be to echo out a `<input type="hidden">` that holds the true/false value and then access the value using JavaScript.

Once you can use your flag, you just need to check the flag in order to decide whether or not to auto-submit or not.

```
if (myFlag){
    //submit form
}else{
    //don't submit form
}
```

This true-false value is not sensitive data so it should be safe to place it as a GET parameter.

Comment: I modified that part so that the form has an id. Auto submit works perfectly but what I want is that if the authentication fails, do not do it again.

Comment: Thanks, the second alternative helped me with the problem. Thank you very much